# Setting a table column's width to max out at the content width of rows below it

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, resize, html-table

I am using Google Chrome to render this HTML page:

```
<html>
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: left;
    }
    td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bobby</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code works fine. Problem is, I want the first column to not resize its width past the width of the longest content width in any row hosted in that column. For example, when I resize the window, I get this:

```
*---------------------------*---------------------------*
|Name                       |Value                      |
*---------------------------*---------------------------*
|Bobby                      |100                        |
*---------------------------*---------------------------*
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
*-----*-------------------------------------------------*
|Name |Value                                            |
*-----*-------------------------------------------------*
|Bobby|100                                              |
*-----*-------------------------------------------------*
```

How can this be done?

PS: I still want to preserve the way the entire table takes up 100% width of the window.

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/uv5Le32y/? Or http://jsfiddle.net/25pjqva4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the width of the `:first-child` to `1px` and it should update the width according to the content.

```
table th:first-child,
table td:first-child {
    width: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbeliv01/ehpvrzk0/

Answer (score 0):

Could try tinkering with percentage based widths to adhere to the table's width

```
    tr th, 
    tr td {
        width: 90%;
        /* adjust this if the "label" column needs to be longer */
    }
    tr th:first-child,    
    tr td:first-child {
        width: auto;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/25pjqva4/

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your first-child column `width:auto` property.

```
table tr td:first-child {
    width:auto;
}
```